# How does Magento save your cart?

Tags: php, magento

Magento has two ways to store a cart. Logged In users can have cart saving defined for as long as you want to define it and it is stored in the database tied to the user number. Non-logged in users seem to be bound by how long your site keeps it's session variables. This leads me to 2 questions.

1) Am I correct in thinking that non-logged in users carts are tied to session timeouts?

2) Since Magento/Varien recommends fairly short times for killing session variables (usually only 4 hours), if question one is true, is there a way to keep a non-logged in cart around without changing the session time out variable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As I understand it carts are saved as quotes, even for guests. Logged in users have a customer ID which is stored with the quote, guests do not so their quote has a null customer ID, hence you may find a store has a lot of orphaned/incomplete quotes in the DB. The only way to associate a guest with their cart is by storing the quote ID in their session.

You could extend how long their quote is available to them by storing the quote ID directly in their cookie with a long timeout but this leads to an obvious security breach; anyone could adjust the value in their cookie and view anyone else's cart.

The only safe way is to proceed is to create a table of guest tokens and associate it with quotes (sorry no code this time, there's too much to explain in a low level). The token is the only public part and is set in the cookie. Tokens should be random and long, say 512-bits/64-chars, but not too long because they are included in every HTTP header. Every time a new session is created it might be a returning guest so check for a token and look it up in the table. Take the found quote ID and store that in the session thereby resurrecting the old cart. Quotes with customer IDs don't need to be rescued this way so should be exempt, especially since a logging-out customer doesn't want to see any part of their account remain visible.

Comment: I'd be interested in making this into a community extension so if you don't feel up to it or don't mind waiting a few months (I have work to do) then let me know here or [there](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer/clockworkgeek).

Comment: When I looked at the flat_sales_quote table and the cookie that is set it completely confirms your analysis. Quotes for anyone is stored in the database and the QuoteID is stored encrypted in the browser cookie. The kill date for the cookie is set to whatever you have defined in Magento Admin. If you add more products to your cart, the cookie is re-saved with a new time. When you log in, Magento merges your existing cart quote with any previous active cart quotes based on your customer account id. So I think some of what you suggest already happens?

Comment: The encrypted value you see in the cookie (probably called `frontend`) is the session ID. Its timeout is what you set in the admin. Since sessions are temporary and bulky they can get flushed even if the timeout is set to a high value. There is no process to flush quotes from the DB so they are effectively eternal, you could set a quote token with a far future time-to-live and it would still work in several years.

Comment: @Lucasmus I wasn't going to since Magento Inc. had added [Persistent Shopping Cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/) but I see that is only for registered customers so I might after all.

Comment: PS.  I did get around to making [a commercial extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/guest-cookies-7130.html) but forgot to write about it here for a while. It is deliberately simple so I just called it [Persistent Guest Carts](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/guest-cookies-7130.html).

Answer (score 9):

Take a look into your magento database at the table "sales_flat_quote"

Regards boti

Answer (score 1):

Carts are saved to the 'sales_flat_quote' table

The items in the basket are saved to 'sales_flat_quote_item', linked by the quote's entity_id

Finally the options of the items are saved to 'sales_flat_quote_item_option' linked by the item_id above

Therefore to view all items and options for a saved quote

```
select sfqi.item_id, sfqio.code, sfqio.value from sales_flat_quote AS sfq, sales_flat_quote_item AS sfqi, sales_flat_quote_item_option AS sfqio where sfqi.item_id = sfqio.item_id AND sfqi.quote_id = sfq.entity_id AND sfq.entity_id = '133940';
```